# Update multiple columns based on other columns in same table

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to update two columns certain values based on two other columns, with certain values in the same table, but they keep coming up with something called bind.

This is what doesn't work:

```
 UPDATE table t1
   SET t1.column1 = value1, t1.column2 = value2
 WHERE t1.column5 = cake
   AND t1.column7 = pie;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are getting an "invalid identifier" error, if my assumption is correct then the only possible mistake in your code is you forgot to enclose your values in single qoutation marks.

```
UPDATE table t1
SET t1.column1 = value1, t1.column2 = value2
WHERE t1.column5 = 'cake'
  AND t1.column7 = 'pie';
```

> Note that if you are assigning/comparing a value with a datatype string, you should always enclose it with `single-qoutation marks`.

Comment: np, if it solved your problem kindly accept the answer.thanks